# need help refactoring this query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I got my query to return what I wanted but it feels like it could have been done a better way. Could someone show me a better way to do this query question, also I'm aware the 'active' column is redundant lets just go with it.

sql fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/18152/53

question -suppose to use subqueries but I couldn't figure it out- : "List all of the library patrons. If they have one or more books checked out, correspond the books to the patrons."

```
SELECT p.name,
    (SELECT checked_in_date IS NULL AS active
     FROM transactions t
     WHERE p.id = t.patron_id AND b.isbn = t.isbn AND checked_in_date IS NULL),
  b.title
FROM patrons p
LEFT OUTER JOIN transactions t
ON p.id = t.patron_id  AND checked_in_date IS NULL
LEFT OUTER JOIN books b
ON b.isbn = t.isbn
```

A desired result would look something like this

```
 name    book_count(optional)  title
 ------------------------------------------
 Hermione Granger   0   (null)
 Terry Boot 1   Advanced Potion-Making
 Terry Boot 1   Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them
 Padma Patil    0   (null)
 Cho Chang  0   (null)
 Cedric Diggory 0   (null)
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: the sample data is in the sql link provided above.

Answer (score 1):

As I read the question, a query such as this does what you want:

```
SELECT p.name,
       ARRAY_AGG(b.title)
FROM patrons p JOIN
     transactions t
     ON p.id = t.patron_id JOIN
     books b
     ON b.isbn = t.isbn
WHERE t.checked_in_date IS NULL
GROUP BY p.name
```